# error: no; dataset in memory has changed since last saved

Tags: dataset, stata

```
use {filename}
no; dataset in memory has changed since last saved
```

I am just beginning to learn Stata and now facing the above issue. I am trying to open >2 different datafiles in one do-file and the error appeared. Is there a way to solve this? I have saved both datasets in the same working directory so the path should be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `clear` before you can `use` a new dataset that hasn't been `save`d.

If the datasets need to be joined, that is a task for `append` or `merge`. If they are separate, you can't open them at the same time. You could open two instances of Stata.

So, a deeper answer depends on what the datasets are and why you want to look at them at the same time.